# Directory.Move() works in debug mode, but not when deployed

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-applications

I have a webapp which has read/write/execute access to an aliased directory.  When I am in debug mode in Visual Studio, the following statement works:

```
Directory.Move("\\\\localhost\\Alias\\oldDirectory","\\\\localhost\\Alias\\newDirectory");
```

The net result is that, `oldDirectory` is now `newDirectory` in the aliased directory.

**But**, when I'm testing this code in pre-production, I have `oldDirectory` and `newDirectory` in the aliased directory.  `Directory.Move` is now behaving as if it is only copying `oldDirectory` to `newDirectory`.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that, instead of using  `Directory` (which is static) I used `DirectoryInfo` which solved my problem.  I think that the heart of the issue was that `Directory` does more security checks than an instance of `DirectoryInfo` does.  I'm still unclear why this is, but it seemed to work.

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely a permissions issue.

The user account that is executing this command probably has Create / Write permissions but not Delete permissions in the aliased directory. I would check whether the user account that the program is executing under has Delete / Delete Subfolders and Files permissions.

**Edit:**

To test this theory, I would temporarily grant the Users group Full Control over the folder to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: How would you go about setting delete permissions?  From what I can tell, if I have write permissions, I also have delete permissions.

To change the permissions of the aliased directory, I do the following:
1) right click the folder, and choose "sharing and security".
2) click on the "web sharing" tab, then click on "edit permissions"
3) on the form that appears, I see only "read", "write", ..., but nothing like "delete".

Am I looking in the wrong spot?

Comment: TBH I'm not sure if granting write permissions from the Web Sharing tab also grants delete permissions. I would expect it to, but you should be able to double-check by looking at the permissions for the individual users / groups on the Security tab. The permissions I referenced above were from the Advanced dialog of the Security tab.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure the folder is not under write-protection and no process is accessing any files at the moment you are trying to move the folder.
- Also check whether you gave the security permissions to the correct user, by verifing under which user account the applicationpool is running.
- You might also want to consider developing on a local IIS to prevent such situations in the future (I've been there; not nice)